# How to stop the car from reading messages out loud?

Tags: cortana, bluetooth

I've paired a Lumia 950 to a GMC Intellilink car audio system. When it connects it connects "voice, music, messages".  When I get a text message, Cortana asks me to "read it or ignore it", but the Intellilink also kicks in and attempts to prompt me via its own screen and voice prompting system to play the message as well.  Cortana voice recognition works well to play back the text, but won't respond to "reply" properly.  I'm assuming this is because Intellilink is interrupting.

Is there a way to have the Bluetooth only connect voice and music, but not messages.  I want to connect via Bluetooth but limit how it connects.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to only have the car reading the messages.

1. Open **Cortana**.
2. Tap **Settings**.
3. Turn off **Read incoming text messages aloud** via Bluetooth.

To have only Cortana reading the messages, turn to the manual that came with the audio system.